# Rotate using Lean Touch and 1 finger

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

How can you rotate a model using Lean Touch in Unity, and only 1 finger? The default appears to be 2.

I tried setting the Required Finger Count to 1, but then nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. Unfortunately, i couldn't figure it out.

Instead I attached the following code to my GameObject. When moving your finger from left to right, the GameObject the script is attached to rotates accordingly around its Z-axis.

```cs
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, -rotationX, Space.World);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the fingers count to 0 in order to be able to rotate it with 1 finger

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  One line answers and code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).