# Lean Rotate Custom Axis with only one finger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, vuforia

I would like to rotate my AR object on itself, so on a single axis, only with one finger. So i use Lean Touch (the free version) and the Script Lean Rotate Custom Axis. 
This process works very well with two fingers, but i don't find the natural movement. I just want that when you slide your finger to the right, the object turns to the right, and vice versa.

I have already found that this question has been asked [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602136/rotate-using-lean-touch-and-1-finger), and tested the proposed answer but it doesnt work. If someone has already encountered this problem or could have a solution, thank you in advance

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, -rotationX, Space.World);
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" makes it sound like it doesn't even compile. Please be more descriptive about what you mean by "It doesn't work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to rather implement actually touch support using [`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) something like e.g.

```
private Vector2 lastPos;

private void Update()
{
    // Handle a single touch
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                // store the initial touch position
                lastPos = touch.position;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                // get the moved difference and convert it to an angle
                // using the rotationSpeed as sensibility
                var rotationX = (touch.position.x - lastPos.x) * rotationSpeed;
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotationX, Space.World);

                lastPos = touch.position;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

or also since Unity also allows [`GetMouseButtonDown(0)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) for the first touch:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        lastPos = (Input.mousePosition);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        var rotationX = ((Input.mousePosition).x - lastPos.x) * rotationSpeed;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotationX, Space.World);

        lastPos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```